# Remove Part of array in a For Loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, arraylist

I am comparing two arrays, if the first array contains a word in the second array then it should delete it from the first array.

```
For Each word In array1
    If array2.Contains(word) Then
        array1.Remove(word)
    End If
Next
```

However when I debug it gives me the following error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

because its updating the array while its trying to iterate through it

Comment: is it an Array or ArrayList?

Comment: This question has been asked **multiple** times. Here's one of many duplicates: [C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/c-sharp-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute)

Comment: Basically dont use `For Each` but `For n` and always loop backwards on a collection type to remove items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq it could look like this. It filteres array1 by array2 and returns new array which contains only items from array1 which are not found in array2.

```
Public Function FilterArrayByArray() As String()
    Dim array1() = New String() {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5"}
    Dim array2() = New String() {"word2", "word5"}

    Return array1.Where(Function(array1Item) Not array2.Contains(array1Item)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem in C# before, assuming it's the same kind. In your example you are using a `for each` loop. Switch to a `for` loop (which has an index).

When a word is found that contains`array2.Contains(word)`, subtract one from the index.

E.G (C#),

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Count; i++) //iterate through the items in array1
{
    if (array2.Contains(word) //if array2 contains word, ...
    {
        array1.Remove(word); //... then remove it, and subtract from i.
        i--;
    }
}
```

That or iterate through array1 backwards doing `--i` above. Both work fine.