# Error for Dictionary, KeyValuePair and altering the data from a key

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

I read those articles:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/c-sharp-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/c-sharp-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute) and [third](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/02/28/enumerating-collections-that-change-in-csharp/) that is only for the case for deleting items, but I am not deleting them.

My Code:

```
 Dictionary<String, Object> tempList =(Dictionary<String,Object>)_ersetzeDasMitDas;

                //pfadFuerDieBildDatei
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> tempData in tempList)
                {
                    if (tempData.Key.Equals("fahrzeugGruppe"))
                    {
                        if (tempData.Value!=null)
                        {
                            if (tempData.Value.Equals("LKW"))
                            {
                                tempList["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"]=  Path.Combine(VirtualMachineKonstanten.statischeDateien, "lkw.png");
                            }
                            else if (tempData.Value.Equals("Transporter"))
                            {
                                tempList["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"]= Path.Combine(VirtualMachineKonstanten.statischeDateien, "transporter.png");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tempList["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"]= Path.Combine(VirtualMachineKonstanten.statischeDateien, "pkw.png");
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //todo: logge Error "fahrzeugGruppe", der Wert ist null ?!
                            //erstmal für Testing
                            tempList["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"]= Path.Combine(VirtualMachineKonstanten.statischeDateien, "pkw.png");
                        }
                    }
            }
```

I get:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute,

after writing `tempList["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"]` and going again to the loop.

How to solve this ?

Comment: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> ErsetzeDasMitDas` signature

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get the updatable elements in the collection, then iterate through the new collection and do the updates:

```
var updatableCollection= tempList.Where(x => 
                          x.Key.Equals("fahrzeugGruppe") && x.Value != null)
                          .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Value);
foreach (var item in updatableCollection)
{
   // check if (item.Value.Equals("LKW"))
   // update the required field
   // rest of condition and updates 
}
```

Comment: I get the same error, when using `var updatableCollection = tempList.Where(x =>
                          x.Key.Equals("fahrzeugGruppe"))
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

                foreach (var item in updatableCollection)
                {
                    updatableCollection["pfadFuerDieBildDatei"] = Path.Combine(VirtualMachineKonstanten.statischeDateien, "pkw.png");
                }`