# Error while adding multiple items to an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

```
for (int i = 0; i < skus.Count; i++)
{
    sku item = new sku();
    item = skus[i];
    sku sku = CompanyDbContext.skus.Where(s => s.item_no == item.item_no).FirstOrDefault();

    if (sku == null) // ok to insert [no duplicate item numbers]
    {
        CompanyDbContext.skus.Add(item);                             
    }

}
CompanyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting

> collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

error. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate question. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-in-arraylist

Comment: That didn't work for me. That's why I asked a new one

Comment: Well, you are basically modifying the same thing you are iterating. Maybe a solution would be to create a temporary list variable where you would add all items that are ok to insert, and then when you loop finishes add them all in one go?

Comment: I tried that thing too.. using CompanyDbContext.skus.AddRange(skuListAdd); but this gave me the same result

Comment: What is 'skus' in the loop definition?

Comment: it's an entity type / a table in the database

Comment: sorry in loop definition it's a - List<sku> skus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this happens because you are modifying the collection which you are looping through as you're performing your work.

One option you have is to create a temporary collection and add your `sku` items to that, and finally add the contents of the temporary `List<sku>` to your `CompanyDbContext`

```
// Create a new temporary list
List<sku> tempSkus = new List<sku>();
for (int i = 0; i < skus.Count; i++)
{
    // Let's assign item to skus[i] immediately, we don't need a new instance here when we're later re-pointing to an existing instance
    sku item = skus[i];

    // Use LINQ Any function to determine whether there are any existing SKU's already
    bool existingSku = CompanyDbContext.skus.Any(s => s.item_no == item.item_no);

    // There are no duplicates, let's add this sku item to our temporary List
    if(!existingSku) 
    {
        tempSkus.Add(item);
    }
}
// Add the Range of tempSkus List to the CompanyDbContext
CompanyDbContext.skus.AddRange(tempSkus);
CompanyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or if you prefer LINQ

```
// Create a new temporary list
List<sku> tempSkus = skus.Where(p => CompanyDbContext.skus.Any(s => s.item_no != p.item_no)).ToList();
// Add the Range of tempSkus List to the CompanyDbContext
CompanyDbContext.skus.AddRange(tempSkus);
CompanyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modify the same thing that you are iterating. As best practice you should update your method something like this:

```
//get search predicat from List<sku> skus
var item_nos = skus.Select(s=>s.item_no).ToList();
//items already in repo
var addedItems = CompanyDbContext.skus.Where(s => item_nos.Contains(s.item_no)).ToList();
var newItems = skus.Except(addedItems).ToList();
foreach(var sku in newItems){
    CompanyDbContext.skus.Add(item);  
}
CompanyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```