# Game will not build because of a Foreach loop in List

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm trying to build my unity project, however I can't as there is a problem with a foreach loop. Just below is the error code I'm receiving, but I don't understand it. Would anyone be able to explain what a possible a solution might be? Or why this error occurs?

InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[UnityEngine.Vector3].VerifyState () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:778)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[UnityEngine.Vector3].MoveNext () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:784)

Player_Movement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player/**Player_Movement.cs:46**)

To give context to be code you draw a line on the screen and it creates a list of vectors for the player to move through.

```
void Update()
{
    //when the player moves their finger accross the screen of the mouse button is held down
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (Input.GetMouseButton(0)))
    {
        //raycasthit variable called hit
        RaycastHit hit;
        //ray variable called ray
        Ray ray;
        //the ray variable is cast between the main camera and the mouse position
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        //if the physics racast hit then calulate the distance betwen the point (mouse position) and the camera
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            //save the positon as the nextPosition
            nextPosition = hit.point;
            //save the nextPositions point's yaxis 
            nextPosition.y = yAxis;
            //if there are positions inside of the position list
            if (positionList.Count != 0)
            {
                //then for each vector3 position in the list
        Line 46  ===> foreach(Vector3 t in positionList)
                {
                    //if there is no posiiton in the list where one should be
                    if (nextPosition != t)
                    {
                        //then create a position
                        positionList.Add(nextPosition);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {   //otherwise create a position in the position list
                positionList.Add(nextPosition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible dup: [so1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute) [so2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-in-arraylist)

Comment: In short, you should not be modifying a list (eg. With `Add()`) while you're iterating through it with a `foreach` loop. Try to restructure your logic so it won't need to do this. Also...not sure your code does what you think it'll do. Currently it'll add `nextPosition` to the list for **every** element in the list that doesn't match `nextPosition`...which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting that exception is that you're trying to modify a collection while you're iterating over it. There are a few ways you can get around this, but probably the best way is to simply test your condition (does the collection contain a specific item) and then modify the collection (add the item) if the test is false.

The Linq extension `Any` comes in handy here. It returns true if any item in the collection matches the condition. Putting a `!` in front of it means you're looking for the case where there are NOT Any items that match the condition:

```
if (!positionList.Any(position => position == nextPosition))
{
    positionList.Add(nextPosition);
}
```

But you can do this without `Linq` also, using the `Contains` method, which is actually simpler and arguably more readable:

```
if (!positionList.Contains(nextPostition))
{
    positionList.Add(nextPostition);
}
```

Note that these answers are also fixing a bug in your code as well. To expose the bug and still avoid the error, you can call `ToList()` on the collection inside the `for` loop, like so:

```
foreach(Vector3 t in positionList.ToList())
{
    //if there is no posiiton in the list where one should be
    if (nextPosition != t)
    {
        //then create a position
        positionList.Add(nextPosition);
    }
}
```

The call to `ToList()` here actually creates a new copy of the list and iterates over that one, so there is no conflict when the original one is modified. However, you will notice that your existing code will add `nextPosition` to the list every time it encounters a non-match, which I don't think is your intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you Rufus! I'm looking into lists and the functionality in unity and there doesn't seem to be a List.Any function. Would you happen to know how I can access this? Is there a collection I need to reference? or is it exclusive to certain types of lists?

Comment: Yeah, it's a Linq extension. You'd need this line at the top of your file: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Amazing! Rufus I could kiss you :D

Comment: @ChrisWinning Please note that this answer *does not* answer question as asked. You should consider to [edit] the question so this post at least can be considered an answer (i.e. by adding explanation of what you trying to achieve). Also note that "build/compile" is very different from "run and get exception".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I modified the answer with some more detail to hopefully better address the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a list (ie `.Add()` to it) while iterating over it.

Find your matching element, then add if necessary:

```
if(positionList.FirstOrDefault(t => nextPosition == t) != null)
    positionList.Add(nextPosition);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response :)  So with positionList.FirstOrDefault it doesn't seem to give me that functionality with lists. Is there a collection I should be using withing unity or does this functionality only work with lists of type int?

Comment: Hey Mathias! Thank you again for your help :D I really appreciate it. I found out I should be using `using System.Linq`