# ASP.NET DefaultBodyModelValidator giving enumerable exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webapi2

We use ASP.NET webapi2 and have lot of jsonconverters implemented as part of our models.

We rarely get below exception, approx once a month.
We don't use any validation attribute on our models.
After reviewing there code many times not sure,what is causing it.

Has anybody face similar exceptions before, any clues.

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext() at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(IEnumerable
>   model, ValidationContext validationContext) at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container,
>   IEnumerable`1 validators) at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext) at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container,
>   IEnumerable`1 validators) at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext) at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container,
>   IEnumerable`1 validators) at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled, model binding module. As we don't need it. To avoid this exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that error normally means that say you had a list of something that amounted to the following:

```
A
B
C
```

Something is inserting something into the list in a way that is causing the list to be modified like so:

```
A
B
D
C
```

for example.  The enumeration throws an exception because it recognized the list was modified; this can commonly happen in a foreach loop.  See this post for more info: [Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024179/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-in-arraylist) as an example.  Using for is a way to get around it.

Did you customize any part of the model binding strategy?

Comment: I had not customized model binding strategy.